# C++ - no operator found

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading

I have a vector filled with values of a custom type and the find() algorithm is complaining that it cannot find a suitable == operator for the value comparison. I've implemented it like this:

```
bool Ship::operator==(const Ship& source) {
    return (_type == source._type &&
            _damagedSquares == source._damagedSquares &&
            _orientation == source._orientation && _state == source._state);
}
```

I've also tried the "friend" method approach but that doesn't work either.
The class itself is structured like this:

```
class Ship {
private:
    ShipType _type;
    int _damagedSquares;
    ShipOrientation _orientation;
    ShipState _state;

public:
    Ship();
    Ship(ShipType type);
    ~Ship();

    bool operator==(const Ship& source);
};
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Additional info:

```
std::vector<Ship> remainingShips;
MultiArray& squares = opponentGridCopy.GetSquares();
for (RowIterator rowIterator = squares.begin(); rowIterator != squares.end();
     ++rowIterator) {
    for (ColumnIterator columnIterator = rowIterator->begin();
         columnIterator != rowIterator->end(); ++columnIterator) {
        Square* current = &(*columnIterator);
        SquareState currentState = current->GetState();
        if (currentState != SquareState::Hit)
            current->SetState(SquareState::Vacant);
        Ship* potentialShip = current->GetOwner();
        if (potentialShip != nullptr) {
            int damagedSquares = potentialShip->GetDamagedSquares();
            if (!damagedSquares) {
                current->SetState(SquareState::Populated);
                break;
            }
            if (remainingShips.empty() ||
                std::find(remainingShips.begin(), remainingShips.end(),
                          potentialShip) ==
                    remainingShips.end()) // should be *potentialShip
                remainingShips.push_back(*potentialShip);
        }
    }
}
return remainingShips;
```

I was passing a pointer as a compare value...
Simply dereferenced it and find() works now.

Comment: Could you please show your container and `std::find` call on it ?

Comment: Are you using `std::vector<const Ship>` ? The above code is fine

Comment: @Venom Could you showthe full error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Ship* potentialShip = ...
std::find(remainingShips.begin(), remainingShips.end(), potentialShip)
```

you're trying to find a pointer while the vector where the search is performed is defined as

```
std::vector<Ship> remainingShips;
```

you're comparing a pointer with a Ship object and thus your comparison is wrong

```
bool Ship::operator==(const Ship& source) // Accepts a Ship reference, not a pointer
```

To fix it either dereference the pointer or change your comparison function.

Answer (score 5):

Declare your comparison operator like so:

```
bool Ship::operator==( const Ship &source ) const
```

Note the trailing `const`.

Comment: MSVC is still returning C2678.

Comment: Can you post the code using a `vector` and `find` as well then?

Comment: @MarcoA. It's certainly part of the right answer, since he didn't declare `operator==` const, when it should have been.

Comment: I agree that it would have been better, but that doesn't solve the problem and according to clang isn't required either

Answer (score 1):

Your

```
bool operator==(const Ship& source);
```

Should be const as well, namely

```
bool operator==(const Ship& source) const;
```

But actually, I prefer to have symmetric operators, *not* as member methods.
Consider:

```
Class Ship
{
private:
    ShipType _type;
    int _damagedSquares;
    ShipOrientation _orientation;
    ShipState _state;

public:
    Ship();
    Ship(ShipType type);
    ~Ship();

    static bool eq(const Ship& s0, const Ship& s1)
    {
        return (s0._type == s1._type &&
        s0.damagedSquares == s1._damagedSquares &&
        s0._orientation == s1._orientation &&
        s0._state == s1._state);
    }

};

inline bool operator==(const Ship& s0, const Ship& s1)
{
    return Ship::eq(s0, s1);
}
```

Comment: More generally, I would simply define a member `isEqual` function, and derive from `ComparisonOperators<Ship>`, a template which provides all of the comparison operators, from `isEqual` or `compare`, depending on what is available.